# check if number is in given range?

Tags: python, range

Given a number and a dictionary with min and max properties, return True if the number lies within the given range (inclusive).

Examples

```
is_in_range(4, { "min": 0, "max": 5 }) ➞ True
is_in_range(1, { "min": 4, "max": 5 }) ➞ False
```

The below code is working for the int values of a number to be searched and dictionary values, but not for float values.

Examples

```
is_in_range(1.8, { "min": 1.25, "max": 1.75 }) ➞ False
```

So far what I tried:

```py
def is_in_range(n, r):
    for i in range(r['min'],r['max']+1):
        if i<=n:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    print(is_in_range(4, { "min": 6, "max": 10 }))
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Rather than looping, you can directly check whether:

```py
if n>=r['min'] and n<=r['max']:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try

```
 def is_in_range(n, r):
     return r['min'] <= n <= r['max']

 print(is_in_range(4, { "min": 0, "max": 5 }))
 print(is_in_range(1, { "min": 4, "max": 5 }))
```

Output

```
True
False
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this

```
r = {'min':4, 'max':5}
n = 1

def isin(r,n):
    return (n>=r['min']) & (n<=r['max'])
```